# R: Removing periods from datasets

Tags: r, regex, dataset, gsub

I'm trying to remove periods/full stops from a column in a dataset (keeping the other variables) using R to analyse data for my thesis.

*Example data entry* 123..67, indicating an event occurs on M,Tu,W,Sa,Su.

My goal is to make subsets for the events on each day.

```
MonOnly <- subset(Test,Test$`Op Days`=="1.")
```

This results in an empty dataset, the period at the end is for regex searching.

The following results in an Invalid Column Index error:

```
MonOnly <- Test[grep("1.",Test$`Op Days`)]
```

AFAIK, `gsub` is only applicable to Strings, yet it does not work for datasets (I still can't seem to figure it out after several hours), as the following command (in order to remove periods) does not work either.

```
Test(`Op Days`) <- gsub("\\.", "", Test$`Op Days`) :
```

Comment: When you say "MonOnly" are you trying to get instances that only occur on Mondays or all instances that occurred on Monday (even if they also happened on other days)?    Do all of them have 7 characters? Is the first character always Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your selection. See here

```
DF <- data.frame(opday=c("1234..7", "1......", ".2.4.67"), x=1:3, y=11:13)
DF
    opday x  y
1 1234..7 1 11
2 1...... 2 12
3 .2.4.67 3 13
```

Then you can create your subsets as follows. For example Tuesdays:

```
DF[grep("2",DF$opday),]
   opday x  y
1 1234..7 1 11
3 .2.4.67 3 13
```

or Monday

```
DF[grep("1",DF$opday),]
   opday x  y
1 1234..7 1 11
2 1...... 2 12
```